# Script installed with setup.py raises ImportError

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py

I am trying to add a runnable script for my project with `setup.py`.  I added it to the `scripts=` argument of `setup`.  The script works fine when I run it from the project, `./solver`.  I install it with `sudo python setup.py install`, and try to run it with `solver`, but I get `ImportError: No module named 'model'`.  How do I correctly install and run my script with setuptools?

```
SOLVER/
    solver/
        model/
            __init__.py
        view/
             __init__.py
        controller/
             __init__.py
        __init__.py
        main.py 
        solver <-- starts the app
    setup.py
    README.md
    LICENCE
```

`setup.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='SOLVER',
    version='1.0.0',
    description='SOLVER app test',
    author=['me'],
    license='BSD',
    classifiers=['Programming Language :: Python :: 3 :: Only'],
    packages=['solver'],
    #packages=find_packages(exclude=["doc", "tests"]),
    install_requires=['numpy>=1.10.4'],
    scripts=['solver/solver'],
)
```

`solver`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from solver import main
main.gui_mode()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to list *all* the packages, including the sub-packages, in the `packages` argument.  You can use `find_packages` to generate that list for you.  Currently, you're just installing the Python files in the `solver/` directory.

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    ...
    packages=find_packages(),
    ...
)
```

You should also use `entry_points` rather than `scripts`, especially when all your script does is import and call one function.  Setuptools will build scripts from the entry points that use the correct Python binary for the env they were installed in.

```
setup(
    ...
    packages=find_packages(),
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'solver=solver.main:gui_mode'
        ]
    ...
    }
```

You can install your package in development mode to get your script, rather than writing it yourself.

```
pip install -e .
```

You should use `pip` to install to the system as well.  It keeps track of what was installed so you can uninstall it later.

```
pip install .
```